# How to properly access nested elements using ng-repeat?

Tags: json, html-table, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat, pug

I have the following JSON objects to be accessed using ng-repeat. I got all the names on the first column instead of grouping into different columns.

```
$scope.tableItems = [
{
  "title": "BUILDING ID",
  "subtitle": [
    {
        "name": "Nexon"
    },
    {
        "name": "Kodak"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lion"
    }
  ]
},
{ 
  "title": "TECHNOLOGY",
  "subtitle": [
    {
        "name": "Robotic"
    },
    {
        "name": "AI"
    },
    {
        "name": "Algorithm"
  ]
}

];
```

I tried to access it like this using jade,

```
    table
        thead
            tr
                th(ng-repeat = "x in tableItems") {{ x.title }} //- get BUILDING ID and TECHNOLOGY
        tbody(ng-repeat = "x in tableItems")  //- get all the NAMEs
            tr(ng-repeat = "(key, value) in x.subtitle")
                td {{ value.name }}
```

And the result returned

```
BUILDING ID                 TECHNOLOGY

Nexon

Kodak

Lion

Robotic

AI

Algorithm
```

I want it to be able to print the table according to the table header, so under

"BUILDING ID" will have only 3 items (Nexon, Kodak and Lion) and for "TECHNOLOGY"

will have (  Robotic, AI and Algorithm ). What's missing on my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "transpose" your data to form the table grid. Currently your data is more suitable to layout multiple rows per column rather than multiple columns in each row as is required when generating table cells using `ng-repeat`.

Extract headings, and modify combine all columns per row:

```
$scope.tableHeadings = _.pluck($scope.tableItems, "title");
    var T = {};
    _.each($scope.tableItems, function (item, colind) {
        _.each(item.subtitle, function (row, rowind) {
            if (!_.has(T, 'r' + rowind)) {
                T['r' + rowind] = [];
            }
            T['r' + rowind].push({
                "name": row.name
            });
        });
    });

    $scope.tableRows = T;
```

Then use it like this in your HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="heading in tableHeadings">{{heading}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, columns) in tableRows">
            <td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{col.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f6shkgm5/1/). I have used the Lodash library here, but you could do without it.